# Blazor MainLayout Child Component Not Refreshing

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

Good Day,
I am new to blazor web assembly. I am writing an application that uses MSAL authentication as the login. I do use the Microsoft azure active directory token to get my access token from the API. The access token has my permissions in it.  Certain screens and pages are permission driven.

Issue:
At the point of login success, I try to get my access token so that I can use it for permission. The access token is been decoded and cashed in local storage. I already created a boolean function that checks for permission and redirects when viewing each component.
The login is successful and my access token is gotten and cashed but the component has already rendered before the access token is fetched.

I want a way to refresh the UI or send a message that permission is already set and the required button should be displayed.

MainLayout.razor

```
 <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
           
                 <Sidebar />
           
        </Authorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

Sidebar.razor

```
 @if (base.HasPermission("")
                        { 
                        <div @onclick="@NavigateBaseOnUserRole">
                            <NavLink href="/admin" class="nav-link-none"  @onclick:preventDefault>
                                <div class="side-menu-item">
                                    <i class="fal fa-cog me-3" style="margin-right: 32px !important;"></i>
                                    Admin
                                </div>
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                     
                         }
```

Index.razor

```
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      
        
        ValidatePermission("");
        await Load(); 
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
```

Basepage

```
 protected void ValidatePermission(string permissionName)
    {
        var hasPermission = authenticationService.HasPermission(permissionName);

        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            RedirectToAccessDenied(permissionName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This has been asked a lot already. There is no change signal going to your SideBar. Consider some StateManager , injectable or as Cascading value. Then subscribe to a change event in SideBar.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman i used a stateManager and it worked